# Interactive grid on top of FBX mesh ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, threejs-editor

[image]

Hey everyone ! I’ve asked a similar question previously regarding covering a custom 3D FBX mesh with a grid of custom cells on Discourse, and someone in the community was very helpful on that post by providing insight shown above on how to implement grid on a non uniform plane using shaders, with mouse highlighting.

However, my main concern is that the shader approach uses realtime mouse position as uniform and applies a color to the cell.

What would be the best approach if I would like to pre-fill some cells on reload of the website, basically having an ID or coordinates for each cell and sending a highlightCell function that could do that. Does this still work using this shader approach ? Or would i have to do another ways of customizing the FBX mesh, or use something else ? Would be grateful for any insight here.

Thanks !